How can I find the fundamental equation of the system?
A gas respects the following equations
$$T=\frac 32(u+\frac 1v)$$ $$P= \frac Tv -\frac1{v^2}$$
Where $T$ is a thermodynamic temperature, $P$ is the pressure, $v$ the specific volume and $u$ the specific internal energy. Find the fundamental equation $u(s,v)$ of this gas.
Discovering information about $u$ through $\frac{\partial u}{\partial V}|_{S}=P=\frac Tv -\frac1{v^2}$ is fairly easy, but the
$$\frac{\partial u}{\partial s}|_{V}=T=\frac 32(u+\frac 1v)$$
part is giving me a bit of a headache. Previously I had already found the fundamental equation $u$ for other systems, but I always knew $s$ in advance. And to add more difficulty, $\frac{\partial u}{\partial s}|_{V}=T$ is also a differential equation now, since $T$ depends on $u$, which has never been the case for me before.
In Callen's book he states that it is possible to obtain the fundamental equation $u(s,v)$ from just the 2 state equations, but I'm having trouble doing that in practice. Do I need to find $s$ before $u(s,v)$ or can $u(s,v)$ be found without knowing $s$ explicitly? In either case, how can I do this?

Try $$du=C_vdT-\left(P-T\frac{\partial P}{\partial T}\right)dV$$
